# Kotlin Retrofit2 make a request with body as raw JSON

Tags: json, api, kotlin, retrofit2

So, I have a challenge to make a sign in and sign up features in Android App but I still confuse about how to implement a kotlin retrofit function that need a parameter body raw json. Here is the API looks like in postman [image: body raw json]

I am using MVVM design pattern and Hilt for Dependency Injection,
these are some of my code related to this case

```
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideRetrofit(): Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideApi(retrofit: Retrofit): Api = retrofit.create(Api::class.java)
```

this is my function

```
    @POST("signin")
    suspend fun signIn(
        @Body raw: JSONObject
    ): SignInResponse
```

this is how I call the function in view model

```
    fun signIn(email: String, password: String) {
        val param = JSONObject().apply {
            add("email", email)
            add("password", password)
        }

        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                signInResponse.value = api.signIn(param)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.d(TAG, "signInError: $e")
            }
        }
    }
```

but it didn't work. I also have tried to change the parameter type from JSONObject to string but it still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I have just found a solution.
The solution is very simple, I just need to change the parameter type from JSONObject to JsonObject. Here is my final code

```
    @POST("signin")
    suspend fun signIn(
        @Body raw: JsonObject
    ): SignInResponse
```

```
    fun signIn(email: String, password: String) {
        val param = JsonObject().apply {
            addProperty("email", email)
            addProperty("password", password)
        }

        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                signInResponse.value = api.signIn(param)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.d(TAG, "signInError: $e")

            }
        }
    }
```

I have tried it and it works fine. I hope it can help you if you guys are facing the same case as me.